# $\rho=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{21}}$, Prove $\rho+\rho^4+\rho^{16}$ is constructible

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Let $\rho=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{21}}$. Prove that the number $a=\rho+\rho^4+\rho^{16}$ is constructible using a compass and a straightedge.

A partial solution was to define a $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism $\sigma:\mathbb{Q}[a] \to \mathbb{Q}[a]$ by $\sigma(\rho)=\rho^4$,  then $\sigma(\rho+\rho^4+\rho^{16})=\rho+\rho^4+\rho^{16}$, i.e.  $\;a \in \mathbb{Q}[a]^{\sigma}$. How can I proceed?

It suffices to build a tower of fields from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}[a]$ of consecutive degrees $2$, and we have $[\mathbb{Q}[a]:\mathbb{Q}[a]^\sigma]=|(\sigma)|=3$ but it doesn't seem to help, since $3 \neq 2$ .

Comment: Hint: The extension $\Bbb{Q}(\rho)/\Bbb{Q}$ is of degree $\phi(21)=12$. You are correct in that $\sigma$ is of order three. Therefore its fixed field is of degree $12/3=4$ over the rationals. You seem to have erred here. The order of a subgroup of the Galoius group tells the degree of the extension BigField/FixedField. Also, the restriction of $\sigma$ to $\Bbb{Q}[a]$ is trivial (which fits the previous sentence!). Can you find the quadratic extension in-between $\Bbb{Q}[a]$ and $\Bbb{Q}$ that you need for constructibility?

Comment: What I think I understood:
I)  $\sigma=id$, so its order is not 3 in $\mathbb{Q}[a]$, and we actually define $\sigma:\mathbb{Q}[\rho] \to \mathbb{Q}[\rho]$.

II)So we make a tower $\mathbb{Q}\subset \square \subset \mathbb{Q}[a]^\sigma= \mathbb{Q}[a] \subset \mathbb{Q}[\rho]$.

Why is it wrong that $$[\mathbb{Q}[a]^1:\mathbb{Q}[a]^\sigma]=[(\sigma):1]=|(\sigma)|=3$$?

Comment: Oh, it's wrong exactly because of I). Do we know that $\mathbb{Q}[\rho]^\sigma=\mathbb{Q}[a]$? (I only see $\supseteq$)

Comment: It probably is true, but equality is not immediately clear. Here's what I had in mind. Find an automorphism $\tau$ of $\Bbb{Q}(\rho)$ such that $\tau^2=\sigma$, $\tau^3\neq 1$. Let $K$ be the fixed field of $\tau$, and $L$ the fixed field of $\sigma$. Show that: 1) $[L:K]=[K:\Bbb{Q}]=2$, 2) $a\in L$, 3) constructibility of $a$ follows from this.